# Move Vtiger 7 Storage and Test directories to a new location

Tags: symlink, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have recently deployed my instance of Vtiger 7 in a load balanced auto scaled configuration.

I have also created a NFS server and mounted this to my Vtiger server. This NFS will also be auto mounted to any additional servers in the auto scaled scenario.

In order for this to all work properly I need to move the /storage and the /test directories to the NFS utilizing a symbolic link.

I have set this up perfectly and also established the proper symbolic links.

Problem I’m running into is that the vtiger will read the data from the symbolic link folders without issue, however is unable to write to these folders due to permissions issues. I’ve set permissions on the NFS folders 775. I’ve also tried 777 permissions just to check it out but still getting the same errors and vtiger will not write to the directories. Any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: I have no answer to your question, but I'm puzzled about why it's not working with 777 permissions. Would like to know the answer for this if you get it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

After burning by eyes our for many hours, I have solved my own question.

The issue was regarding folder ownership settings. I essentially needed to change the symlink owner and the NFS directory owner to the same owner as the CRM web root.